# OOP in Python / Tkinter: how to define a module with a support class in which all widgets events are defined

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I'm quite new with OOP. Let's say I have defined a Tkinter application in a file called *myApp.py*. This is its content:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.constants import *

import myApp_support

class App(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.title('myApp')
    self.resizable(False, False)
    self.state('zoomed')

    supportClass = myApp_support.AppSupport()
    
    ...

    # %% BUTTON OPEN FILE
    self.Button_OpenFile = ttk.Button(container)
    self.Button_OpenFile.configure(text='''OPEN UBX FILE''') 
    self.Button_OpenFile.configure(command = supportClass.Button_OpenFile_Clicked)

    ...

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = App()
        app.mainloop()
```

*container*, in the previous code, is the frame to which the button is anchored. I would like to define a class (*AppSupport()*) in another file (*myApp_support.py*), in which all events related to the app widgets are defined, such as a button clicked event.
The class should define a variable that points to the window, as defined in *myApp.py*, in order to manage all the widgets.
I tried unsuccessfully with this code saved in the *myApp_support.py*:

```
import myApp

class AppSupport():
    def __init__():
       global rootApp
       rootApp = myApp.App()
    
    def Button_OpenFile_Clicked(*args):
        print('Open Button clicked')
```

How can I define properly the class according to this scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the instance of `App` to `AppSupport`

```
class App(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    ...
    self.supportClass = myApp_support.AppSupport(app=self)
    ...
```

```
class AppSupport():
    def __init__(self, app):
       self.app = app
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work to me. It gives me an error at line _supportClass = myApp_support.AppSupport(app=self)_ : __init__() got multiple values for argument 'app'

Comment: @eljamba: my apologies. I forgot to add `self` to `AppSupport.__init__`.

Comment: No problem! Now it works fine! I would like to access to all the children objects of the app in each method defined into the _AppSupport_. I guess I could pass _self_ as an argument of a method, and then have access as _self.app.myObject_. Is there a shorter method to do this? Maybe with a global variable or declaring _self.app_ as an attribute of the class?

Comment: @eljamba: every methos should already be defined to accept `self` -- that's fundamental to how classes and objects work. That is the correct way to do if. If you're using classes you should not be using global variables.

Comment: I tried two different strategies: the one you suggest defining an istance variable _app_ in _init_ and, in an analogous way, declaring a class variable _app_ and defining it in the _init_ method. Both works properly. My only complain regards the accessibility of the children objects of the app. With both strategies I have to check the name of the button, for example, and the name of the property I want to modify. No hints appear from the intellisens when I write the full stop after the object name. What about using the _import_ as in my code? How can be your solution be modified accordingly?